# Which distro to switch to (laptop)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, power-management, wine, distributions

I switched to Linux Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 8.1 about a month ago because I wanted to get more out of my laptop (Lenovo Flex 2). I have been trying to either solve or ignore some issues that I have encountered, however, by now I am contemplating returning to Windows, whuch I really do not want to. I wonder if there is a more suitable distro for my laptop.
The issues I have with Ubuntu:

- Battery life - Ubuntu is 3 times more power hungry than Windows was and it is the main problem, considering I'm running it on a laptop that is supposed to be portable
- Buggy audio
- Gaming (not crucial, but still) - Wine just doesn't seem to work with ANY game I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General notes:

With the current user basis and the company support for Ubuntu, I would assume that this is currently one of the distros with the broadest hardware and software support.
Ubuntu itself is Debian-based, but with Debian's focus on stability (for good reasons), Debian usually does not offer the latest software versions. So if you want to switch distros, I (personally!) would suggest you (especially!) taking one of the Ubuntu-based ones (Mint being the most prominent one). Why so? a) it would be similar to your system and you would skip a lot of relearning, b) your software can largely be the same, c) the actuality is given, d) large user base will lead to many problems being solved.

However switching disto might not even be necessary.

Battery issue:
One of the main battery drains is always your desktop environment. Try something less resource hungry compared to Unity (assuming you have a clean Ubuntu installation). XFCE or LXDE are said to be lightweight, but there are many alternatives.

Sound issue:
As said before: with Ubuntu being one of the major distros, I would assume this problem is either already targeted, or that someone could help. I would suggest to locate the actual issue and to ask a separate question concerning this (probably over at askubuntu).

Games issue:
Alternatively to wine (or `playonlinux` - which is wine-based) you might want to take a look into whatever valve is doing with steam - or some day a proper steamOS version. Many games are supported already and this might solve many of your problems. Apart from that many things work with wine, so probably `winetricks` could help you in installing missing libraries.

Note that any distro-related suggestions are prone to be opinion-based, so decide with care.